# Run 2 wormholes on the same Raspberry Pi with Dataplicity

Tags: python, nginx, flask

So I have a simple web page that runs on Nginx and has Rest API calls to a Python Flask app.
I'd like to put them through 2 wormholes on [Dataplicity](https://docs.dataplicity.com/docs/host-a-website-from-your-pi). One for the web page and the other one for the backend app.
At the moment I can only do either. Is there a way to make it work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yep, put nginx in front and park the apps under different locations.

Let's say your app is listening on port 8080 and the other app on port 8081. 
 Then your nginx config might look like this:

```
server {
    listen       ...;
    ...
    location /app1/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
    location /app2/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    }
    ...
}
```

Which means your apps will be accessible locally as:

- http localhost/app1/
- http localhost/app2/

This will appear as this on Dataplicity wormhole:

- https 123123123.dataplicity.io/app1/
- https 123123123.dataplicity.io/app2/

Hope that helps :)

M.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I just opened my nginx.conf and I don't see any server {} entry.. Should I just add it?

Comment: I have another issue here. My backed is a Flask app and I need to run it and use a certain port. If I try to start nginx with the same port it will fail to start: 
Jul 13 16:40:53 DietPi nginx[3637]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:5000 failed (98: Address already in use)

Comment: If you move Flask to an alternative port (I know you said you need to run it on a particular port but bear with me), then add another nginx location in the root space that just forwards to your Flask app, this will likely work..... and your Flask app will appear in the same location as before (just with nginx in the middle).